# How can I throw a body?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

When I am silently clearing an area often I would like to throw a corpse into a hole, over a cliff or elsewhere to hide it.

Currently I can only drop the body, which causes the cadavre to roll off my back onto the floor.

Can I throw a body?

Comment: HNQ here we come!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> You throw them the same way you shoot with your bow too.
>   **When you carry a body just aim and throw**.

- On PC, this means that,

  > while carrying the body, *hold right-click and left-click*.
- On Xbox,

  > *hold LT and tap RT*.
- On Playstation 4,

  > *L2 to aim, R2 to throw*.

<sup>sources: [1](https://steamcommunity.com/app/812140/discussions/0/1732090362055344028/), [2](https://steamcommunity.com/app/812140/discussions/0/3397295779067591124/), and [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/assassinscreed/comments/a3nh8w/throwing_bodies_in_ac_odessey/)</sup>